# Suspension functor of pro-spaces to pro-spectra preserves weak equivalences

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff, spectra

Suppose we have the category $\mathrm{sSet}$ of simplicial sets and $\mathrm{sSpectra}$ of simplicial spectra. Then we have the functor $\Sigma^{\infty} \colon \mathrm{sSet} \to \mathrm{sSpectra}$, $X \mapsto \Sigma^{\infty} X$, where $(\Sigma^{\infty} X)_n = \Sigma^n X = S^1 \wedge X$. We can then go to the pro-categories $\mathrm{Pro}(\mathrm{sSet})$ and $\mathrm{Pro}(\mathrm{sSpectra})$ of Pro-objects and get the functor $\Sigma{\infty} \colon \mathrm{Pro}(\mathrm{sSet}) \to \mathrm{Pro}(\mathrm{sSpectra})$ by applying $\Sigma{\infty}$ to each component of a pro-object.

We have now cohomology of pro-objects, via $H^*(X;M) = \mathrm{colim}_i H^*(X_i; M)$ for a pro-object $X$ and an abelian group $M$ (regardless if $X$ is a pro-simplicial set or a pro-spectrum). A $\mathbb{F}_2$ cohomologycal weak equivalence is a map $X \to Y$ which induce an isomorphism $H^*(Y; \mathbb{F}_2) \to H^*(X; \mathbb{F}_2)$. I want to prove that $\Sigma^{\infty}$ preserves these $\mathbb{F}_2$ cohomological weak equivalences. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: do you know how to do this classically?

Comment: What do you mean by classically?

Comment: What is the simplicial structure on $\Sigma^\infty X$?  If it's the constant one, then I don't see why you want to consider simplicial spectra at all.

Comment: @Candyblock say for spaces

Comment: @Andres Mejia No I dont know how to do it

Comment: @JHF I want to consider it, because in the paper I am currently reading, there is a statement about a functor $F \colon \mathrm{sSpec} \to \mathrm{grAb}$ and that $F$ sends weak equivalences to isomorphisms, and $F$ induces then the functor $F \circ \Sigma^{\infty} \colon \mathrm{sSet} \to \mathrm{grAb}$ and I want to prove that $F \circ \Sigma^{\infty}$ still sends weak equivalences to isomorphisms by proving that $\Sigma^{\infty}$ preserves weak equivalences.